# cloud init installation - copy files from iso

Tags: system-installation, cloud-init

I'm looking for a way to copy file from the automate installation of ubuntu20/ubuntu22 LTS.
I created special ISO with user-data commands but the last I am trying to do is to copy a file to a specific directory.
Thanks in advanced
Update: I try to add the commands to this section but it didn't work

```
late-commands:
    - |
      sudo mkdir /mnt/lp1
      sudo mount -o loop /dev/cdrom /mnt/lp1
      ls -lha /mnt/lp1
      sudo cp /mnt/lp1/katello_server-host-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/katello_server-host-cert.crt
      sudo umount /mnt/lp1
      sudo update-ca-certificates
      cat <<EOF > /target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/80_my.cfg
      hostname: ubuntu-$(openssl rand -hex 3)
      manage_etc_hosts: true
      preserve_hostname: false
      EOF

      ls -lha /mnt/lp1 >>> in this line I can see the files of the iso but the cp dont work ( I didn't sow any issues)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cloud init installation - copy files from iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422753/cloud-init-installation-copy-files-from-iso)

Comment: It seems you accidentally double posted - please delete this question. Thanks. 

Comment: Deleted the other post

Comment: You can loop mount the iso file and copy the files available at the mount point. If the files you want to copy are in the squashfs file, you can loop mount that file (while keeping the first loop mount) and then the files in the squashfs file are available to copy.

Comment: How can I do it?  can you write me the command or any example

Comment: Discussion in [chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138426/discussion-between-sudodus-and-hellboy).