# Cloud init copy files from iso don't work

Tags: cloud-init

I'm looking for a way to copy file from the automate installation of ubuntu20/ubuntu22 LTS. I created special ISO with user-data commands but the when I am trying to do is to copy a file to a specific directory it seems working but after the restart when you finish the installation I don't see the file in the path any more.
Thanks in advanced

```
late-commands:
    - |
      sudo mkdir /mnt/lp1
      sudo mount -o loop /dev/cdrom /mnt/lp1
      ls -lha /mnt/lp1
      sudo cp /mnt/lp1/katello_server-host-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/katello_server-host-cert.crt
      sudo umount /mnt/lp1
      sudo update-ca-certificates
      cat <<EOF > /target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/80_my.cfg
      hostname: ubuntu-$(openssl rand -hex 3)
      manage_etc_hosts: true
      preserve_hostname: false
      EOF

  ls -lha /mnt/lp1 >>> in this line I can see the files of the iso but the cp dont work ( I didn't sow any issues)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cloud init installation - copy files from iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422754/cloud-init-installation-copy-files-from-iso)

Comment: Please update your existing question if you want to add more details.

Comment: If you wish, I can remove my comments and answer from your old thread. It might or might not improve the chances that someone else will help you. I'm waiting for your decision: remove or keep?

Comment: You can keep the the comments.

Comment: I didn't mange to solve the issue muru

Comment: OK, I'll keep the comment but remove the answer. Good luck getting help from someone who knows about cloud init installation :-)

Comment: Thanks on everything sudodus :)